# Can anyone help me in making an extra page in magento which is not in the theme by default?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add an extra button  "ADD Prescriptions"  to my product page within Add to cart button, my website is about eye glasses. just like this: `http://www.fashioneyewear.com/oliver-peoples-gregory-peck-ov5186.html`

This button leads to an extra page which is not included in my theme by default. This page is very muck like: `http://www.fashioneyewear.com/prescription/index/index/id/31460/?super_attribute[233]=342979&super_attribute[194]=328200`

Can anyone helps me in making this page in magento as i can't do this??

Comment: What would you like to accomplish on the ADD Prescriptions page?